# Is there a place to ask questions that are more opinion-based than fact-based without them being closed?

Tags: discussion, support

I was just creating a question about the following on Drupal Answers:

> I know this is a general question and there isn't a single correct answer, but I'd like to know the community's general sense.
>
> As the only web developer in my company, as I get requests for increasing our website's functionality and adding on features, I sometimes wonder about the trade-off between too much functionality and 'just the right amount' of functionality.
>
> Are there some vague guidelines or perceived best-practices about how many modules are too many for a small-to-medium company website in Drupal?
>
> If performance is not an issue, are there still some guidelines for what's maintainable and good practice in terms of the website's long-term goals.
>
> Sorry if this is too general. Just wondering what others are thinking...

Before I even saved it, based on the title I gave my post, the system said it was likely to be closed for not being constructive. I understand that, and noticed a couple of similar, though slightly different questions that had been closed in the past.

Is there a place anywhere on Stack Exchange where discussions about trends and practices can take place (vs. just programming questions)? If not, where are folks discussing such topics and would it make sense to have/create a space on Stack Exchange for such discussions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would vote to close this here as being "not constructive" for DA, but that could potentially be a decent question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, where less concrete questions are tolerated (to an extent).

The question would have to be edited to not be specifically about Drupal, though Drupal can be mentioned.  It would also have to be tailored to be a little less vague.  Something like:

> I am the only web developer in my company.  I frequently get requests to add new features to our website.  What is a good strategy for sorting out the requests for features for the sake of adding something (ie, fluff) versus features that will be good for the site in the long run?

Hopefully @MarkTrapp will see this answer and comment, as I think he is a moderator there.

Comment: OK.  Thank you.  I'm getting a sense of things and understand that discussion questions are closed fairly quickly.  Will certainly work within the system and not post them in the future, but do still wish there was a space on Stack Exchange for such questions!  It's such a good community that I know I'd get good quality opinions. :-)

Comment: Mark Trapp is not anymore a moderator there. Not constructive questions are not accepted on Programmers too, since it changed its topic; see [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/311/the-lifecycle-of-cool) as example. Now Programmers is, "a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development"; the difference with Stack Overflow is that on Stack Overflow you ask questions about the code, where on Programmers you ask questions where you don't still have code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, when did Programmers change its focus?  I don't hang out there much, but don't recall seeing anything about this on Meta.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3415/44). It happened before the site graduated.

Answer (score 1):

In the few Stack Exchange sites where Drupal questions are on-topic, not constructive questions are closed. That is true for any Stack Exchange site, as all Stack Exchange sites have the "not constructive" closing reason.

> We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

The only place on Stack Exchange where not constructive questions are allowed are the chat rooms. There is [a chat room dedicated to Drupal Answers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers), but it's not much frequented. As alternative, there are [chat rooms for Stack Overflow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active); maybe there is a chat room dedicated to Drupal, but I have never used it, and I cannot say if it used from many users.

Outside Stack Exchange, you can try on [the IRC channels dedicated to Drupal](http://drupal.org/irc).

Comment: Hi kiamlaluno.  I do understand that rule exists, which is why I didn't post my question and started this topic instead.  I would love to have a discussion about the above, but don't want to do it against any community rules.  So I'm wondering if you have thoughts on the 'If not' part of my question: 1) do you have an idea where folks may post such subjective questions (even if it's not here) or 2) whether it is a good idea to think about developing such a space on Stack Exchange?  This is the only place I thought to see if others feel similarly that there is a need for this...

Comment: Thank you! +1 for all those extra suggestions.  I personally would feel a little weird having such a meaty discussion on chat, but didn't even know that was an option!  Thanks again.